# database management for item recommendation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am collecting user review from my site. Review can have 1,2,3,4,5 rate.

From each review I am collceting list of adjectives. So I will have good, nice, great, excellent etc scrapped from these reviews.

Currently I am taking adjectives from review and storing into table. I append each new set of adjectives coming from reviewa with previous list.

Then I have seperate function call to which counts occurrence of each word and store into another table.

What I want:

I want to create review recommendation which grade the recommendation system based on adjective occurrence.

Depending on how many adjectives (good, great,nice etc) count review has, it will be ranked. `Good` in 4 star review has more value then good in 3 star review.

means displaying the best review (4-5 star) having maximum positive adjectives.

I am wondering how should I manage my database so that I can get rid of this in faster way.

any thought would be highly apprecited.

review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I think making query - `select review from table where max (good,nice,great) and business_type = 'xyz' order by review_rate desc;` will do.

for `max (good,nice,great)` - selecting reviews from table in which contents adjective which have highest occurence. how can I make query for this?

I have seperate table which contains words and occurrence

```
word   count
-------------
good    463
great   345
nice    321
best    234
```